# how to get single data from a text file in c# without using ReadtoEnd() that can be of array type integer

Tags: c#-4.0, project

```
string file = "file.txt";
StreamWriter o = new StreamWriter(file);

int num = 5;
o.Write(num);//i have saved num as integer.

o.Close();
StreamReader op = new StreamReader(file);
Console.WriteLine(op.ReadToEnd());// this will show me num whis is 5 but i cant use num any morre as 5.
int b=op.read();//i want b to hold num value after it read.
op.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

So from what i see you consume the 5 when you do `op.ReadToEnd()` so if you just have the num 5 in the file doing just `op.Read()` should do the trick alternatively you can use `op.Peek()` to return the value without consuming it

if your still confused check
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netframework-4.8)